# Calling WSASend from C#

Tags: c#, marshalling, winsock

Here is my code which I had no success with:

```
Unmanaged.WsaBuf buffer =
    Unmanaged.WsaBuf.Create("Blah Blah");

IntPtr bufferPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(buffer));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(buffer, bufferPointer, true);

IntPtr o;
SocketError error = Unmanaged.WSA_Send(
    socket,
    bufferPointer,
    1,
    out o,
    SocketFlags.None,
    IntPtr.Zero,
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

And here is method declaration:

```
    [DllImport("Ws2_32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "WSASend")]
    public static extern SocketError WSA_Send(IntPtr socket, IntPtr buffer, int len, out IntPtr numberOfBytesSent, SocketFlags flags, IntPtr overlapped, IntPtr completionRoutine);
```

And this is my WSABUF declaration:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct WsaBuf
{
    public ulong Len;

    public IntPtr Buf;

    public static WsaBuf Create(string str)
    {
        byte[] connectBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(connectBuf, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        return new WsaBuf { Buf = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject(), Len = (ulong)connectBuf.Length };
    }

    public void Free()
    {
        if (!Buf.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            GCHandle.FromIntPtr(Buf).Free();
        }
    }
}
```

I receive nothing on other side. Any Idea?

Comment: Why would you use WinSock when .NET exposes TcpClient, and even the `Socket` class?

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is a hooking situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u_long` is `unsigned long`, which maps to `uint` because it is a 4 byte quantity on Microsoft Visual C compiler. `Len` should be `uint`. Probably, `WSASend` only looked at the first 4 bytes, found them to be `0` which is a zero length buffer.

Btw, you are misusing `GCHandle.FromIntPtr`. Look at the docs to see what it really does. It is immaterial to the question, so I won't elaborate.

Comment: But it is u_long on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Works, Need to fix other things as well but it seems this was the way to solve sending problem.